# Azure HDI cluster delete recreate question?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-hdinsight

Is the below option supported .

1. Create a Azure HDI cluster(non ESP as ADDS is not configured) and later when the ADDS is available, Delete and recreate a ESP enable cluster. Will there be any issue with accessing the existing data?
2. Create a Azure HDI cluster with a temporary ADDS(actual ADDS migration may take time) and later when the correct ADDS is available, Delete and recreate the cluster with correct ADDS. Will there be any issue with accessing the existing data?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, you can access the existing data in Azure HDInsight.

You can store data in Azure Blob storage, Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1, or Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2. Or a combination of these options. These storage options enable you to safely delete HDInsight clusters that are used for computation without losing user data.

**Note:** We recommend using separate storage containers for your default cluster storage and your business data. The separation is to isolate the HDInsight logs and temporary files from your own business data. We also recommend deleting the default blob container, which contains application and system logs, after each use to reduce storage cost. Make sure to retrieve the logs before deleting the container.

Azure HDInsight follows a strong separation of compute and storage-- as such the recommendation is to store your data either in Azure Storage blobs and Azure Data Lake Store, or a combination of the two. Both provide an HDFS compatible file system that persists data even if the cluster is deleted.

The benefit of this approach is:

- The data is persistent, even after you delete your HDInsight cluster.
  This means it will also be available without any data transfer effort
  should you deploy a new cluster to perform additional processing.
- The costs for storing your data are predominalty driven by the volume of
  data stored and tranferred, which can be signficantly less than the
  costs for running a cluster.
- The data is available for multiple clusters to act upon.

[image]

For more details, refer [Azure Storage overview in HDInsight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/overview-azure-storage) and [Use Azure storage with Azure HDInsight clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage)

Comment: Thanks Pradeep.Few more questions on same topic:
1) In option 1, when ESP is enabled at the creation of new cluster, we need to setup the permissions at ranger level? correct?
2) For option 2, what issues we can see when we are moving the cluster from one ADDS to another ADDS?